# What if I don't have enough space on my main memory to run a program?

Tags: java

So, I'm just starting Java and on [this](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap01/ch01_14.html) website, it says that the operating system tries to find an unused section of the main memory that is large for the application. What happens if there isn't enough space?

Comment: You will get an error. In practice, either you need a lot of memory and your make sure you run on a decidated, properly sized server. Or you don't and you make sure you don't use more than xxx MB and you will be fine on most (even average) computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when there isn't enough memory depends on your operating system. Some less sophisticated operating systems would display an error asking you to manually close some applications to free up memory. Other operating systems would try "swapping out" one of the running applications to disk to free up space in main memory. If there is not enough physical memory to fit your application even after swapping out everything else, these operating systems would display an error.

Note that the above applies only to the initial load of the application into memory for running. Most applications would request additional memory as they run to store their data. Some applications would also request loading additional executable code through dynamic libraries. If the OS does not have enough memory to complete any of these operations, it would return an error to the application, which must then handle the situation by freeing up some of the resources it no longer needs, or exiting gracefully if there is no possibility of continuing without acquiring additional memory.

Comment: `Some less sophisticated systems` There is out there any OS that does not support virtual memory and with a Java port to it?

Comment: So, say I was playing an online game, such as League of Legends, and I ran out of room to continue playing the game, would my computer crash? Or would the game just get slower.

Comment: @Drakojan The answer depends on the application. It may gracefully handle the situation by informing you that there's not enough memory, or try cleaning up some of the memory that it no longer needs. However, lots of applications would indeed crash when there's not enough memory.

Comment: @SJuan76 There are multiple unsophisticated (by today's standards) embedded platforms that run Java. For example, I am not even sure if there even was any swap space on phones that ran Java eight years ago.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have enough memory, the program does not execute (unless your computer can go to the shop and buy some more memory by itself. Mine can't).

That said, not all memory is the RAM, because OS support virtual memory so part of the memory available to it is really a hard disk swap file. Also, with Java and some windows (at least XP), if you need a lot of memory you have trouble because, even if there is enough, it is often partitioned and the JVM needs it to be in a single "block". But you have to need a lot of it for the problem to be experienced.

Answer (score 0):

If there is enough memory on your system to run the JVM but not enough to run your Java program, you will likely have an OutOfMemoryException.